# Access Win Partition in Terminal Mac OS X

Tags: linux, windows, macos, terminal

Is it possible to access (mount?) a partition in Mac OS X through the Terminal? Located at /Volumes/Windows HD/...

I have VMWare fusion, but is it possible to access files through the Terminal?

Aside: Does anybody have a definitive guide/list/cheatsheet for Terminal functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was actually able to solve this by enabling **"Open Command Window Here"** in OS X. This can be accessed via **System Pref > Keyboard > Keyboard Shortcuts > Services**. Using this method, right click on a folder in Win partition via OS X's Finder and voilà!